# Unit Tests to check app's battery usage

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I was reading Android Developers pages about testing and came across this recommendation about checking battery usage: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/what_to_test.html

In this page they explicitly talk about Unit Tests to achieve the result. What I can't understand (and can't find in the documentation) is how I actually should write the code to do it. Any suggestion or, even better, any example?